# Build solution only if old in VS Macro IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

Using the Visual Studio Macro IDE, how can I tell if a build is old or outdated?

I currently have my F5 remapped to run a custom macro that will go into debugging mode and attach to the browser without building the solution. Normally, I would always make sure to hit Control-Shift-B before debugging, but I thought I could take a step further and program this process into the macro too. The best part of this setup is that if I did not change the code since the last build, **I can always jump in and out of debugging without redundantly rebuilding the solution like when using the normal Debug (F5) mode.**

Basically, I want to know if there is either a variable or some process to tell whether or not the code has been changed since the last build.

Here's the macro in its entirety, with the ??? part showing what I'm trying to do. Use it for yourself if you'd like--it saves me tons of time when debugging large solutions.

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module AttachToWebServer
    Public Sub AttachToWebServer()
        Dim AspNetWp As String = "aspnet_wp.exe"
        Dim W3WP As String = "w3wp.exe"
        Dim buildIsOld As Boolean

        buildIsOld = ???

        If buildIsOld Then
            ' Build the solution and wait for it to finish
            DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)
        End If

        ' Are we at a breakpoint?
        If DTE.Debugger.CurrentMode = EnvDTE.dbgDebugMode.dbgBreakMode Then
            DTE.Debugger.Go() ' Then continue instead of reattaching
        Else ' If not, attach to IIS
            If Not (AttachToProcess(AspNetWp)) Then
                If Not AttachToProcess(W3WP) Then
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Process {0} or {1} Cannot Be Found", AspNetWp, W3WP), "Attach To Web Server Macro")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function AttachToProcess(ByVal processName As String) As Boolean
        Dim processFound As Boolean = False
        For Each Process As EnvDTE.Process In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses
            If (Process.Name.Substring(Process.Name.LastIndexOf("\") + 1) = processName) Then
                Process.Attach()
                processFound = True
            End If
        Next
        Return processFound
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: You may want to try and find a way to do this without macros for the sake of maintainability, VS2012 and newer do not support macros. Also I'm pretty sure VS does this for you automatically anyway.